# Load validations on Div load

Tags: jquery, validation, html, onload

I have multiple Divs on my page(using updatepanel), only one visible at a time. on the third div, i have to implement validations using jquery.

---

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#btn_Save").live("click", function () {
               jQuery("#form1").validate({
                   rules: {
                       '<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>': {
                           minlength: 2,
                           required: true
                       },
                       '<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>': {
                           required: true,
                           email: true
                       }
                   }, messages: {}
               });

               var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
               prm.add_initializeRequest(onEachRequest);
           });

       function onEachRequest(sender, args) {
           if (jQuery("#form1").valid() == false) {
               args.set_cancel(true);
           }
       }

    </script>
```

and 
at the bottom of the page :

```
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            fn_init();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

---

Now, the validation script is loaded on page load and does not fire when div is visible(on some button click). SO i need to load all the validation script on div load, or if somebody can suggest better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#form1").validate({ 
   ignore: ":hidden" 
});
```

Comment: @user1042813     function onEachRequest(sender, args) { 
           if (jQuery("#form1").validate(ignore:":hidden") == false) { 
               args.set_cancel(true); 
           } 
       }